# What's wrong with CalendarApp.createCalendar options?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a script to create and share a calendar with Google Sheets, but it seems that I can't get everything I would like to, the options are not working. Here is the code:

```
function createCalendar() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Détail");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  
  const calName = sheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue();
  const year = sheet.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
  const color = sheet.getRange(3, 4).getBackground();
  const calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar(
    `District ${nomCal}`, 
    {
      summary: `Here you'll find all the importants events in the ${district} for the year ${year}`,
      timeZone: "Europe/Paris",
      color: color
    }
  );
  
  console.log('created calendar "%s", with ID : "%s", description: "%s" and color: "%s".',
    calendar.getName(), calendar.getId(), calendar.getDescription(), calendar.getColor());
```

the calendar is created but the summary is empty

The log:

23:18:45    Infos   Création du calendrier "Province PACA", avec ID : "ID@group.calendar.google.com", description: "" et couleur: "#ff9900".

I checked the scopes, everything seems ok, I don't understand.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected summary? What do you expect this `('some text "%s"', year)` to do?

Comment: a very simple description of the calendar like "here you will find all the importants events for the year 2022-2023", the year being a user input in a cell.

Comment: The year is probably empty in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates all expressions and returns the right most. So, `('some text "%s"', year)` just  evaluates to `year`( which is probably empty, in this case).

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead:

```
summary: `some text ${year}`
```

The `color` should be a specific color from [`CalendarApp.color`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/color):

```
color: CalendarApp.Color.BLUE
```

or a hexColor string retrieved from `getBackground`:

```
color: color //or just color( without :)
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a result using setDescription after creating the calendar:

```
function createCalendar() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("focus");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  
  const calName = sheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue();
  const year =  sheet.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
  const color = sheet.getRange(3, 4).getBackground();
  const description = sheet.getRange(5, 1).getValue();
  
  //Création du calendrier
  const calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar(
    `${calName} district`, 
    {
      timeZone: "Europe/Paris",
      color: color
    }
  );

  calendar.setDescription(`${calName} district calendar for the year ${year}\n${description}`)
```

Thanks for your help!